# turbolinks rails 5 toggle event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Here is my coffee script

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#comments-link').click ->
    $('#comments-section').toggle()
```

Here is my .scss file

```
#comments-section{
 display: none;
}
```

hers is the HTML file

```
<%= link_to 'Comments','#', id: "comments-link"%> 

<div id="comments-section">
   <%= render @recipe.comments %>
</div>
```

When I click on the link, nothing happens.
In the web console, the code works without any error.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

ok i figured out that i had to preventDefault()

```
$('#comments-link').click (e)->
  e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work in Rails 5 you need to add the gem:

gem 'jquery-rails’, ‘4.3.1'

Then in 'app/assets/javascripts/application.js' you need to require jquery by adding the first line of the following (the other 3 lines are already in that file):

```
  //= require jquery
  //= require rails-ujs
  //= require turbolinks
  //= require_tree .
```